# XSLT transformation stripping all namespaces from soap:env

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this Input XML to which i need to apply the XSL and transform it to a another XML which is on higher version. Lets say V3. So input XML is on version V1.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
      xmlns:NS1="http://www.test1/Error/v1"
      xmlns:NS2="http://www.test1/Error/schema/SCRIPT"
      xmlns:tns="http://www.test1/webservice/Service/v1"
      xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tns:Sample>
         <NS2:Message release="006" version="010">
            <NS2:Header>
              <NS2:TestMessage>1</NS2:TestMessage>
              </NS2:Header>
            <NS2:Body>
               <NS2:SampleTx>
                  <NS2:Element1>
                     <NS2:IdName>
                        <NS2:ID>
                           <NS2:IDValue>114</NS2:IDValue>
                         </NS2:ID>
                     </NS2:IdName>
                  </NS2:Element1>
                  </NS2:SampleTx>
            </NS2:Body>
         </NS2:Message>
      </tns:Sample>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The XSL I am applying is

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:djh="http://www.test1/webservice/Service/v1"
    xmlns:NS1="http://www.test1/Error/v1"
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|comment()|processing-instruction()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="djh:*">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="http://www.test1/webservice/Service/v3">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:element>  
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:element>      
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and the output I get is

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tns:sendCancelRx xmlns:tns="http://www.test1/webservice/Service/v3">
         <NS2:Message release="006" version="010"
               xmlns:NS2="http://www.ncpdp.org/schema/SCRIPT">
            <NS2:Header>
             <NS2:TestMessage>1</NS2:TestMessage>
             </NS2:Header>
            <NS2:Body>
               <NS2:SampleTx>
              <NS2:Element1>
                 <NS2:IdName>
                    <NS2:ID>
                       <NS2:IDValue>114</NS2:IDValue>
                   </NS2:ID>
                 </NS2:IdName>
              </NS2:Element1>
              </NS2:SampleTx>
            </NS2:Body>
         </NS2:Message>
      </tns:sendCancelRx>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

It strips all the namespace declaration from `xmlns:NS1="http://www.test1/Error/v1" xmlns:NS2="http://www.test1/Error/schema/SCRIPT" xmlns:tns="http://www.test1/webservice/Service/v1" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"`

and the output I want is

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
      xmlns:NS1="http://www.test1/Error/v3"
      xmlns:NS2="http://www.test1/Error/schema/SCRIPT"
      xmlns:tns="http://www.test1/webservice/Service/v3"
      xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tns:Test>
         <NS2:Message release="006" version="010">
            <NS2:Header>
               <NS2:TestMessage>1</NS2:TestMessage>
              </NS2:Header>
            <NS2:Body>
               <NS2:SampleTx>
          <NS2:Element1>
             <NS2:IdName>
                <NS2:ID>
                   <NS2:IDValue>114</NS2:IDValue>
               </NS2:ID>
             </NS2:IdName>
          </NS2:Element1>
          </NS2:SampleTx>
            </NS2:Body>
         </NS2:Message>
      </tns:Test>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I would appreciate if someone could let me know what is missing from my XSL.

Comment: Excellent question: showing input, output, code, and desired output.

Comment: What processor are you running? When I execute your stylesheet with Saxon and Xalan it reports the following error: `XTDE0830: Undeclared prefix in element name: NS2` http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#err-XTDE0830

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following XSLT preserves all of the namespace declarations (used and unused) and changes the `tns` namespace-uri to `http://www.test1/webservice/Service/v3`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:djh="http://www.test1/webservice/Service/v1"
    xmlns:tns="http://www.test1/webservice/Service/v3"
    xmlns:NS1="http://www.test1/Error/v1"
    xmlns:NS2="http://www.test1/Error/schema/SCRIPT"
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|comment()|processing-instruction()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="djh:*">
        <!--reconstruct an element using the new v3 namespace,
            but use the same namespace-prefix "tns"-->
        <xsl:element name="tns:{local-name()}" 
                     namespace="http://www.test1/webservice/Service/v3">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:element>  
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">    
            <!--copy all of the namespace declarations, 
                except for "tns" - which is v1 in the source XML -->
            <xsl:copy-of select=
                    "namespace::*
                    [not(name()='tns')]"/> 
            <!--copy the namespace declaration for "tns" from the XSLT,
                which is v3, and add it to the element-->
            <xsl:copy-of select=
                "document('')/*/namespace::*[name()='tns']"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It produces the following output with Saxon 9.x (does not preserve unused namespaces with Xalan, but that apparently is due to [XALANJ-1959](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/XALANJ-1959)):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                  xmlns:NS1="http://www.test1/Error/v1"
                  xmlns:NS2="http://www.test1/Error/schema/SCRIPT"
                  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xmlns:tns="http://www.test1/webservice/Service/v3">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <tns:Sample>
            <NS2:Message release="006" version="010">
                <NS2:Header>
                    <NS2:TestMessage>1</NS2:TestMessage>
                </NS2:Header>
                <NS2:Body>
                    <NS2:SampleTx>
                        <NS2:Element1>
                            <NS2:IdName>
                                <NS2:ID>
                                    <NS2:IDValue>114</NS2:IDValue>
                                </NS2:ID>
                            </NS2:IdName>
                        </NS2:Element1>
                    </NS2:SampleTx>
                </NS2:Body>
            </NS2:Message>
        </tns:Sample>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you say that it's stripping all those namespace prefix declarations. It strips those that aren't needed, but it leaves the declarations for `NS2` and `tns` (and `soapenv`).

Having declarations for namespace prefixes that are unused accomplishes nothing. Why do you care? All the elements in your output XML are in the correct namespace. That's what matters to any downstream XML consumer.

(I'm assuming that the change of the namespace URI for `NS2` is not part of the problem you're trying to solve.)

XSLT makes sure that each element in the output XML is in the proper namespace. Other than that, it doesn't offer fine control over where namespace prefixes are declared, because it doesn't affect the semantics of the output XML.

Comment: If I've misunderstood your requirements, please clarify.

Comment: I agree my output XML does have all the necessary namespace and is properly transformed. But still want to control the stripping of un-used name space. There has to be a way to do that.

Comment: Change of name spaace for NS2 is intentional and yes you are right tha is not an issue.

Comment: @Guest, did you see Michael Kay's answer? Did `xsl:copy` accomplish what you wanted?

Answer (score 2):

The difference between `xsl:element name="{name()}"` and `xsl:copy` is that `xsl:copy` copies the namespace declarations, while `xsl:element` doesn't. So use `xsl:copy` if you want them retained.